# How to disable Fiddler from posting XmlHttpRequests?

Tags: post, xmlhttprequest, fiddler

Maybe my question has both the parts , how does fiddler overcome CORS and posts requests ?
Is it something that our application at the server is allowing it to ?

Comment: Fiddler is *not a browser* so does not need to implement the same protections as a browser *chooses* to do.

Comment: So does that mean that I could write server code to POST XmlHttpRequests to another domain ?

Comment: Yes, its the browser that prevents Ajax from working across domains not the underlying network protocols.

Answer (score 1):

To better understand Same-Origin-Policy, and why browsers need CORS, see this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/28/explaining-same-origin-policy-part-1-deny-read.aspx

Yes, you can send requests to any origin from your server:

> **Couldn’t the attacker’s server simply make a direct request to the victim server?**
>
> A key point in all of this is that abusing the user’s browser to load content from the
> victim server sends that user’s authentication (cookies, credentials, etc) to the victim
> server. The attacker needs these credentials to be sent to the victim server in order to
> get access to content worth stealing.
>
> Stated another way, if the attacker could directly download protected resources
> from `yourbank.com` without using your browser, he absolutely would do so. But he can’t,
> because only your browser has the cookies and credentials that yourbank.com requires in
> order to return protected content.